# how to replace the code which has deprecated classes

Tags: spring-batch

Currently I am using the below code in spring batch job. how to replace the code in the latest version of spring since the class is deprecated in latest versions.

```xml
<beans:bean id="vms.batch.vrsToAnalysis.vendorSetter" 
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.resource.ListPreparedStatementSetter" >
    <beans:property name="parameters">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>1</beans:value>
            <beans:value>1</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>       
</beans:bean>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at the official java doc: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.7/api/index.html?org/springframework/batch/item/database/support/ListPreparedStatementSetter.html

It suggests to use `ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter` instead. Your xml snippet should then look somewhat like this:

```
<beans:bean id="vms.batch.vrsToAnalysis.vendorSetter" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter">
  <beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:array>
      <beans:value>1</beans:value>
      <beans:value>1</beans:value>
    </beans:array>
  </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>
```

Answer (score -2):

Replacing org.springframework.batch.core.resource.ListPreparedStatementSette with org.springframework.jdbc.core.ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter did the trick.

Comment: his doesn't add anything that isn't already in the given and upvoted answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).